# Excel VBA: ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add from multiple resources into the same sheet fires A table can't overlap error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script in an Excel sheet, 
It' basically query some data from an access database like this:

```
 With ActiveSheet
            Set x = .ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array("ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=" & dname & ";DefaultDi"), Array("r=I:\Pems Filter\Pems Filter\AccessDatabase;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;")), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable

            With x
            .CommandText = Array( _
            "SELECT newTable.Field1, newTable.Field2, newTable.Field3, newTable.Field4, newTable.Field5, newTable.Field6, newTable.Field7, newTable.Field8, newTable.Field9, newTable.Field10, newTable.Field11, newT" _
            , _
            "able.Field12, newTable.Field13, newTable.Field14, newTable.Field15, newTable.Field16, newTable.Field17, newTable.Field18, newTable.Field19, newTable.Field20, newTable.Field21, newTable.Field22, newTab" _
            , _
            "le.Field23, newTable.Field24, newTable.Field25" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM newTable newTable" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE (newTable.Field2=" & detectorid & ")" _
            )
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = False
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .PreserveColumnInfo = False
            .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database_1"
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With
        End With
```

The problem here, I've multiple Access databases, each one is have the same table exactly, I tried to make a loop where I do this query against a list of Access databases like this:

```
For i = 1 To Application.CountA(listDatabases)
    dname = databasename & "\" & listDatabases(i)

    With ActiveSheet
            Set x = .ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array("ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=" & dname & ";DefaultDi"), Array("r=I:\Pems Filter\Pems Filter\AccessDatabase;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;")), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable

            With x
            .CommandText = Array( _
            "SELECT newTable.Field1, newTable.Field2, newTable.Field3, newTable.Field4, newTable.Field5, newTable.Field6, newTable.Field7, newTable.Field8, newTable.Field9, newTable.Field10, newTable.Field11, newT" _
            , _
            "able.Field12, newTable.Field13, newTable.Field14, newTable.Field15, newTable.Field16, newTable.Field17, newTable.Field18, newTable.Field19, newTable.Field20, newTable.Field21, newTable.Field22, newTab" _
            , _
            "le.Field23, newTable.Field24, newTable.Field25" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM newTable newTable" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE (newTable.Field2=" & detectorid & ")" _
            )
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = False
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .PreserveColumnInfo = False
            .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database_1"
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With
        End With
Next i
```

But no hope, I keep getting this error:

[image]

Any solution?

Comment: Of course it overlap, you have to change the `Destination:=Range("$A$1")` when adding each list object. But this doesn't make sense as you will have 10 tables if u have 10 access source, which might as well just get data directly from the access source. Consider put all data into a single table using `listobject.listrows.add`

Comment: @Rosetta I removed `Destination`, then tried `listobject.listrows.add`, but no hope.

Comment: what does no hope mean? Did you get an error message? If so which, and on what line?

Comment: @xsari3x, you have to lock in the destination, otherwise excel doesn't know where you want to place the new table.....